# Book set in England about a substance from the sewers that transforms organic matter into itself, and is stopped by iodine

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember a book set in England about a substance that was in the sewers which comes up, and every time it touches something organic, it transforms it into itself.

- The hero uses iodine to stop it and herd it into specific directions.
- It had a very strange picture on the cover and was a green book.
- It was a '60s or '70s book, I think.

Any ideas what the title was? I keep thinking "The Clone" or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty much the plot of'The Clone' by Theodore L. Thomas and Kate Wilhelm, which was a Berkley paperback in 1965', though it was set in Chicago.   It's many years since I read it, but as I remember, the Chicago setting was fairly central to the plot, with great efforts being made to prevent the green slime from reaching Lake Michigan and thus spreading all over the US, and maybe the entire world... In the end, it was destroyed, but the book ended by recalling the genesis of the slime (leftover hamburger scraps reacting with a mixture of cleaning fluids in a janitor's mop bucket) and pointing out how easily it could happen again.

Comment: Thanks sooooo much. I guess not England after all. Yes this is the book I remember. I read it when I was a boy and just remember it being so vivid in its explanations and action.